# Fractional output dimensions of "sliding-windows" (convolutions, pooling etc) in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

As far as I can see, ResNet-152 ([paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf), [visualization](http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/gist/d38f3e6091952b45198b), [Caffe Model](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/master/prototxt/ResNet-152-deploy.prototxt)) expects inputs with dimensions 224x224x3, and its first layer does 64 convolutions, each against a 7x7 kernel with a padding of 3 and stride=2.

Since $\frac{\text{input}+2\times\text{padding}-\text{filter}}{\text{stride}}=112.5$, its output's dimensions should be 112.5x112.5x64 (right?). This must be converted to an integer, and it looks like Caffe "truncates toward zero" and the output's dimensions are actually 112x112x64 ([here's the code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp)), and I loaded the model with Caffe and verified it).

This seems to be different than Caffe's strategy for pooling layers ([code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp)), which ceils the result, instead of truncating it.

My questions:

1. What's the conventional way of treating settings of kernel/padding/stride that results "fractional" dimensions (e.g. 112.5 as above).
2. Are the common frameworks (Caffe, TensorFlow, Torch...) consistent about it?
3. Is the inconsistency between the behaviour of convolutional layers and pooling-layers of Caffe is "by design"? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

The fraction part comes from the stride operation. Without stride, the output size should be `output_no_stride = input + 2*pad - filter + 1 = 224`. With stride, the conventional formula to use is `output_with_stride = floor((input + 2*pad - filter) / stride) + 1 = 112`.

In many programming languages, the default behavior of integer division is "round toward zero" so the floor operation can be omitted when the numerator and denominator are positive integers. (Ref: [Caffe's convolution implementation](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp#L18-L19), [Cudnn docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#cudnnGetConvolutionNdForwardOutputDim))

Comparing the output dimension with and without stride

```
output_with_stride = floor((input + 2*pad - filter) / stride) + 1
                   = floor((output_no_stride - 1) / stride) + 1
                   = ceil(output_no_stride / stride)
```

---

Caffe's pooling is a bit complicated, it first replaces the floor with ceiling, then decreases the size by one if the last pooling does not start strictly inside the image, as shown in the [code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp#L90-L105).

```
  pooled_height_ = static_cast<int>(ceil(static_cast<float>(
      height_ + 2 * pad_h_ - kernel_h_) / stride_h_)) + 1;
  pooled_width_ = static_cast<int>(ceil(static_cast<float>(
      width_ + 2 * pad_w_ - kernel_w_) / stride_w_)) + 1;
  if (pad_h_ || pad_w_) {
    // If we have padding, ensure that the last pooling starts strictly
    // inside the image (instead of at the padding); otherwise clip the last.
    if ((pooled_height_ - 1) * stride_h_ >= height_ + pad_h_) {
      --pooled_height_;
    }
    if ((pooled_width_ - 1) * stride_w_ >= width_ + pad_w_) {
      --pooled_width_;
    }
    CHECK_LT((pooled_height_ - 1) * stride_h_, height_ + pad_h_);
    CHECK_LT((pooled_width_ - 1) * stride_w_, width_ + pad_w_);
  }
```

I think the result is mostly aligned with the conventional formula except when the last pooling is entirely outside the original input.