# How to know the shape of the future feature maps knowing the shape of the kernel applied in an image?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

Let's say that I have a [32*32] image and i want to convolve a 5*5 filter on it. The result of this convolution will be a 28*28 image.

But how do we know that it will give a 28*28 image. Is there a formula to assert ?

[A Beginner's Guide To Understanding Convolutional Neural Networks](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner's-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/)

Comment: They state in the article: "The reason you get a 28 x 28 array is that there are 784 different locations that a 5 x 5 filter can fit on a 32 x 32 input image. These 784 numbers are mapped to a 28 x 28 array."

Comment: yes but why are there 784 different locations that a 5 x 5 filter can fit on a 32 x 32 input image.?

Comment: You start with filter taking the first 5 cells out of 32, meaning you have 27 left, so you have 27 + 1 positions filter can take horizontally. Then you move it down and get 27+1 positions vertically.

Comment: it also depends on other operations like padding and stride, you can take a look at this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223630/fractional-output-dimensions-of-sliding-windows-convolutions-pooling-etc-in/223697#223697